# text not visible in powerpoint slide with apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I use apache POI to create a Powerpoint using Java. **I need to add a text on top of an image.** I run this code:

```
XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
XSLFSlide slide = ppt.createSlide();

XSLFTextBox shape = slide.createTextBox();
XSLFTextParagraph p = shape.addNewTextParagraph();

XSLFTextRun r1 = p.addNewTextRun();
r1.setText("The");
r1.setFontColor(Color.blue);
r1.setFontSize(24);
```

The text `"The"` is visible while projecting, but **not visible in the powerpoint editor**.

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of what you're getting and what you expect?

Comment: I have http://www.heberger-image.fr/data/images/42274_have.jpg and I want http://www.heberger-image.fr/data/images/98621_want.jpg

Comment: not visible on powerpoint editor: http://www.heberger-image.fr/data/images/60671_not_visible_on_powerpoint_editor.jpg          visible on diaporama: http://www.heberger-image.fr/data/images/96699_visible_on_diaporama.jpg

Comment: formatting, rephrasing and removed some unnecessary tags.

Comment: For the ones who are still wondering about this, we need to set an anchor in order for the shape to be visible i.e `shape.anchor = Rectangle(x, y , width, height)
`